# How many hours the computer is running for upgrade linux ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04

I tried to upgrade my linux ubuntu to version 12.04. Now, it is about 24 hours my computer is running and upgrading is not finished. What I should do?

Comment: can you find a error message or something? or can you post a screen shot of the update screen?

Comment: Is it frozen?  Do you have a really slow connection?

Comment: I cannot see any error message

Comment: I am in the step installing and upgrade

Answer (score 0):

That's three or four times as long as any Ubuntu install or upgrade I've ever experienced, and I've done something like 40 or 50 of them.

Did your internet perhaps go down? Check your router. You did back up all your user files before you started, right? Because this is why you never trust any upgrade or install procedure that's supposed to leave your data untouched. It's still probably there, safe and sound, but if you have to start over, you may end up doing an install from a DVD or live USB.

If you do end doing a re-install, you should still be able to copy your user data off to a USB drive by booting from an install disk or DVD and choosing "Try out Ubuntu without installing".